# Get number of pass/fail test cases of allure report by mail from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins, allure

I am trying to send a mail for number of pass and fail testcases after running Jenkins job. I am using allure for report generation and the code using testNG framework. I have installed email extension plugin as well in Jenkins. **How I can get these numbers on mail?**

I think I will be able to resolve my problem if I can get the variable to be used for them. May be they can look like: $FAILED_TESTS, $PASS_TESTS, $PASSED_TESTS, $SKIPPED_TESTS, $CANCELED_TESTS, $BROKEN_TESTS etc. **These variables do not works. I wanted correct variable names.**

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can get any properties from Allure report.

Publish TestNG report as job step and then just send email with your jelly template using [Email ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

```
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME"}
```

For example my looks like:

[image: For example my looks like]